# apply over nested functions

Tags: r, functional-programming, apply

This is not really a problem, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution:

Lets say i have a vector `vec <- rlnorm(10)` and I want to apply a not vectorized function to it, e.g. `exp` (ignore for the moment that it is vectorized), I can do

```
sapply( vec, exp )
```

But when the function I want to apply is nested, the expression becomes directly less simple:

```
sapply( vec, function(x) exp( sqrt(x) ) )
```

This happens to me all the time with the `apply` and `plyr` family.

So my question is, is there in general an elegant way to nest (or pipe) functions without defining explicitly an (anonymous) function `function(x){...}`? Something like

```
# notrun
sapply( vec, sqrt | exp )
```

or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package **functional** includes a `Compose` function.

```
library(functional)
id <- Compose(exp, log)
id(2) # 2
```

Its implementation is simple enough to include in your source, if, say, you don't need the rest of the stuff in the **functional** package.

```
R> Compose
function (...) 
{
    fs <- list(...)
    if (!all(sapply(fs, is.function))) 
        stop("Argument is not a function")
    function(...) Reduce(function(x, f) f(x), fs, ...)
}
<environment: namespace:functional>
```

Comment: `sapply( vec, Compose( exp, sqrt ) )` works like a charme. @HongOoi I don't see why this wouldn't work with not vectorised fucntions. Just tried it and it works fine: `library(Rdisop)
sapply( molecularFormula, Compose( getMolecule, getMass ) )`. `getMass` and `getMolecule` are not vectorised.

Answer (score 6):

See the examples for `?Reduce`:

```
## Iterative function application:
Funcall <- function(f, ...) f(...)
## Compute log(exp(acos(cos(0))
Reduce(Funcall, list(log, exp, acos, cos), 0, right = TRUE)
```

Here's a more bare-bones implementation with a slightly different interface:

```
Compose <- function(x, ...)
{
    lst <- list(...)
    for(i in rev(seq_along(lst)))
        x <- lst[[i]](x)
    x
}

sapply(0, Compose, log, exp, acos, cos)
```

Comment: +1 I have not even thought of using `Reduce` for this. Plus, I like your `Compose` function more than the `functional::Compose`. So it's really har to decide what is the better answer. But since I was looking more for a builtin function, I'll go with the functional package.